# Keeping the original css style

Tags: mediaelement.js

When i am using mediaelement.js on audio or video tags which have a specific style (margin, float, etc...) render is not good.

Is there a way to keep the original css style on mediaelement.js render ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem with this code :

```
$(function(){ 
    $("video,audio").mediaelementplayer(); 
    $("video,audio").each(function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".mejs-container").css("float", $(this).css("float")); 
        $(this).css("float", "none"); 
        $(this).parents(".mejs-container").css("marginTop", $(this).css("marginTop")); 
        $(this).parents(".mejs-container").css("marginRight", (($(this).css("marginRight")=="0px")?"auto":$(this).css("marginRight"))); 
        $(this).parents(".mejs-container").css("marginBottom", $(this).css("marginBottom")); 
        $(this).parents(".mejs-container").css("marginLeft", (($(this).css("marginLeft")=="0px")?"auto":$(this).css("marginLeft"))); 
        $(this).css("marginTop", "auto"); 
        $(this).css("marginRight", "auto"); 
        $(this).css("marginBottom", "auto"); 
        $(this).css("marginLeft", "auto"); } 
    ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of variations of how the media element player gets rendered.  For type video/youtube, it actually becomes an iframe.

But I was able to to determine the id from looking at the inspector in developer tools.  For the me the id was 'mep_0'.  So, I was able to add:

```
#mep_0
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Not elegant, but it works.